onMouseDown does not fire until after the mouse is released
EDIT: possibly a dupe of this: How can I make Mousedown/Mouseup trigger on mobile devices?
In this setup, "onMouseDown" will not appear in the log until after I release the mouse. I am on Chrome with Linux Mint.
EDIT: Here's a huge clue as to what's going on that I just discovered. This is only happening when I go into the Chrome dev tools and click on "toggle device toolbar" which puts the screen into mobile mode.
Code:
  useEffect(() => {
    const onMouseUp = () => {
      console.log('onMouseUp')
    }

    const onMouseDown = () => {
      console.log('onMouseDown')
    }

    window.onmouseup = onMouseUp
    window.onmousedown = onMouseDown

    return () => {
      window.onmouseup = null
      window.onmousedown = null
    }
  }, [])

Does anybody have any insight into this? I am completely at a loss here.

Does this answer your question? How can I make Mousedown/Mouseup trigger on mobile devices?

yes, I wish I would have seen this post earlier that would have saved me tons of time.

You can mark this as a dupe if you want, although it might be better for the community to let this post stay here.  It will rank in SEO differently than the post you linked. People just trying to figure out why onMouseDown isn't firing until after release, totally unware that it is a mobile issue, won't be searching for press events in google, so that link will not find them.

I didn't make it an actual vote since the JavaScript tag makes it a single-vote close for me and I wasn't entirely sure that was the problem.  Though as I was struggling to re-create the behavior, the question edit led me to the right place.  I may be out of close votes for the day anyway, but even if someone else comes along and marks this as a duplicate I wouldn't vote to delete it or anything like that.  If nothing else, I can attest to the fact that I just learned this behavior because of this question.

I'm not familiar with the mechanics of stack overflow so I didn't understand most of that, but I think I get the overall sentiment

In the Chrome dev tools in mobile mode, onMouseDown does not trigger the same way it does in desktop mode. Adding in mobile events such as onTouchStart will solve this problem (assuming the cause of the problem for you was the same for me.)

John Miller's answer is correct in general sense - events for touch devices are different than mouse devices. And when touch devices first started to come around they had to make some decisions so that the web wouldn't break on touch devices, so they mapped certain mouse events to some touch counterpart. You will likely run into problems trying to handle both mouse events and touch events in a sane way.
Fortunately, Pointer Events were created to help alleviate this issue and create interoperability between any device with a "pointer".
Here's the main points:

Pointer events inherits from mouse events
Helps handle any pointer: mouse, stylus/pen, touch, etc
Handles multitouch: touchscreens with a mouse, multi-touch (ex. pinch zoom), etc

